# Publish multiple websites with shared BLL and DAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure, tfs

I have a solution with the following projects:

Solution
 - Website1 project (Asp.Net MVC, azure website project with code first migration)
 - BLL project (Class library)
 - DAL project (Class library)
 - Website2 project (Asp.Net MVC, azure webrole project)
 - Website2.Azure project (Cloud project for Website2)

Both website1 and website2 uses the BLL and DAL projects for business logic and dataaccess. When I change the DAL models i DAL classlibrary and run the code first migration in Website1 project the database structure is changed in development database.

And when I publish the website1 project to Azure websites the production database structure is updated automaticly and Website1 works fine in production, but then the production code for website2 stops working because the production code for website2 is using the old BLL and DAL for the updated database structure..

So my question is:
How do I manage this in the best way?

1. Can I deploy the 2 websites/MVCprojects to Azure at the same time in a smart way? Using continous deployment, TFSPreview or something..? (One of them publishes to azure websites and the other to azure webrole)
2. Is there a way to tell website2 that it doesn't matter if the db structure has changed, continue anyway (offcourse there would be an error if a property is missing when trying to use it, but the rest could continue to work until an update/publish of website2)..
3. Any other idea...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi my response will fall under ‘Any other idea’ category..

If your BAL depends on DAL then certain type of changes will affect BAL. For example let’s say you have a schema on which you have tables A, B and C. You DAL expose all these tables as business entities and the BAL is exposing operations to manipulate them.

Now, if you delete table C and regenerate DAL, BAL will break as it will no longer be able to find C in DAL.

But if you add a new entity E and regenerate DAL, BAL should not suffer as it is not using E for any of its operations.

One thing that you can do to minimise these sort of strong coupling is to introduce Data Transfer Object pattern. With DTO pattern you will package your DAL entity/entities into a total separate class and use that class to communicate with the outside domain.

Now if DAL changes, it would be up to the DAL how to propagate those changes up to the rest of the calling code (BAL in this case). If DAL deletes C, it can still keep the DTO that represents C and take a specific action when asked to by upper layer code (such as passing null when asked for a list of C..)

Usually DTO pattern is used to communicate between UI and BAL, but could be used to communicate from DAL to BAL as well.

One downside of this is you will be adding another layer of complexity to your code. So you should think and eliminate any other potential solutions before this.

This solution is not specific for Azure, but a very generic one which you may use in with any n-tier solution

Happy Coding

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I use DTO's from BLL, I convert the DAL models to DTO's in the BLL layer.. But, I think that project in someway reacts when DAL Context "feels" that there is a change in DB structure..? And suggests to do a code first migration or something..?

Comment: Mattias, Migration would change the schema through EF. If you use Code First and POCOs you are in control of the shape of the schema. Try placing all your POCO’s off and away from the main DAL assembly into a domain entity assembly and get DAL and BAL to reference the domain entity assembly. And if your project time line permits try to define an interface to define DAL operations and get the DAL to implement it and BLL to consume it. This would be the ultimate decoupling and if done correctly, your layers could change independently without affecting the others

Comment: Ok... Sounds great! I don't exactly know how to accomplish that.. What happens then If I change one of the models in the domain entity assembly? Does the code first migration in website1 detect that..?